# Calling CloseMainWindow() from a service

Tags: c#, service

I made a C# Windows Service (Windows 10, Framework 4.8, 32 bits) from which I would like to gently close other Windows programs (form or WPF) such as Notepad.  I used CloseMainWindow() to play nicely with other applications, but CloseMainWindow() always returns false when called, even if Notepad is freshly opened, nothing typed in.  Also tried MSWord with same result.  However, if I run the same piece of code in a Windows console app CloseMainWindow() works very well.  Thinking it may be a credentials thing I tried running the service as LocalSystem, LocalService and as myself (local admin) with same results.

If I use Kill() instead of CloseMainWindow() it does close Notepad (and others) from within the service, but Kill is not gentle.

So I thought there may be known limitations to calling CloseMainWindow() from within a service.  I searched quite extensively but this is one of the rare occasions where Google was of no help.  This is why I'm calling to the community for help.  Thank you!!

Comment: Windows Services can't interact with the user session. `Kill` is killing the process, not closing the window. Consider running an application (no/hidden window) in the user's session and letting the service tell it which window it wants to close.